# find the inverse of a hyperbolic function

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Hi everyone I am new in *Mathematica* and I am trying to find the inverse of a function which contains hyperbolic tangents and I hope someone can help me.

The function is

y=(a)tanh(d(x-g))+ (a/2)(tanh(d(m+g))-tanh(d(m-g)))

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post with actual and correct *Mathematica* code, e.g., use `Tanh[d (x - g)]` rather than $tanh(d(x - g))$.  Also, what are your $d$, $m$, and $g$ &mdash; particular constants or arbitrary constants (perhaps with some conditions placed upon them)?

Comment: Will you be happy with an inverse function involving `ArcTan`? If so, try `InverseFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
InverseFunction[a Tanh[d (# - g)] + a/2 (Tanh[d (m + g)] - Tanh[d (m - g)]) &][y]
```

gives the output

$$ \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a \tanh (d (m-g))-a \tanh (d (g+m))+2 y}{2 a}\right)+d g}{d}$$

together with the warning that $\tanh^{-1}$ is a multivalued function.